# Xfinity internet is causing me to have "bad requests" / error 400 to URL - reg.usps.com

Tags: http-status-codes

I am encountering an HTTP error 400 when trying to reach reg.usps.com

USPS has verified their site is up.

The error is repeatable on all devices in household, connected to xfinity. On PCs, have tried multiple browsers, Chrome, Edge, with & without a private/incognito tab

The main site  - [www.usps.com](http://www.usps.com) - works fine.

All other websites work as expected.

https://www.usps.com
works on PCs and phone's Xfinity WiFi connection.

https://informeddelivery.usps.com (similar login procedure as reg.usps.com)
doesn't work on PC or phone's Xfinity WiFi connection.

https://reg.usps.com (you are redirected to this site from click & ship - cns.usps.com)
doesn't work on PC or phone's Xfinity WiFi connection.

Informed Delivery site works OK on phone's LTE data connection.

reg.usps.com site works OK on phone's LTE data connection.

cns.usps.com site redirects to reg.usps.com and works OK on phone's LTE data connection.

Same results whether PC HOSTS is enabled or disabled.

Changing Windows 10 DNS from auto to Google DNS made no difference.

Flushing the Win 10 DNS cache made no difference.

Winsock reset made no difference.

"Protected Browsing" is OFF.

"Managed Sites" is Disabled.

Incognito browsing window made no difference.

Changed from Google DNS to OpenDNS in router settings
Rebooted router multiple times
Xfinity tier 1 support asked if [www.americanexpress.com](http://www.americanexpress.com) was working. Then they "provisioned" my modem and had me unplug/replug modem.

Xfinity support ticket is escalated but tier 2 agent said she would have to call her team and then call me back...

Browser results:

PC Google Chrome: "This page isn’t working... HTTP ERROR 400".

PC Edge: "This page isn’t working... HTTP ERROR 400"

Android chrome browser with Xfinity WiFi: "This page isn’t working... HTTP ERROR 400"

***EDIT***

Developer tools shows these errors:

(index):1 GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=%3CGTM-MVCC8H%3E net::ERR_ABORTED 404

(anonymous) @ (index):1
(anonymous) @ (index):1
cns.usps.com/:1199 Access to font at 'https://www.usps.com/assets/fonts/d5af76d8-a90b-4527-b3a3-182207cc3250.woff' from origin 'https://cns.usps.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.usps.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

main-sb.css:1 GET https://www.usps.com/assets/fonts/d5af76d8-a90b-4527-b3a3-182207cc3250.woff net::ERR_FAILED 200

cns.usps.com/:1199 Access to font at 'https://www.usps.com/assets/fonts/4a9c62ab-b359-4081-8383-a0d1cdebd111.woff' from origin 'https://cns.usps.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.usps.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

main-sb.css:1 GET https://www.usps.com/assets/fonts/4a9c62ab-b359-4081-8383-a0d1cdebd111.woff net::ERR_FAILED 200

cns.usps.com/:1199 Access to font at 'https://www.usps.com/assets/fonts/5b4a262e-3342-44e2-8ad7-719998a68134.woff' from origin 'https://cns.usps.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://www.usps.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin.

main-sb.css:1 GET https://www.usps.com/assets/fonts/5b4a262e-3342-44e2-8ad7-719998a68134.woff net::ERR_FAILED 200

main.70fb2fe4.chunk.js:1 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'items')
at main.70fb2fe4.chunk.js:1:938322

Comment: You probably need to escalate at your ISP and also contact UPS about the issue by their Support Phone number.

Comment: Suggest to open Network log in one of your browser's developer tools. There is a sequence of 40-50 network requests that occur when you click "Click&Ship", giving you an account login page, if successful. There may be an indication there of where the process goes wrong. Can't see that your ISP has anything to do with it.

Comment: Ignore the .map 404 errors, those are DevTools looking for DevTools-specific files.

Comment: removed the devtool 404 errors. added other errors.